# Checkstyles + Gradle throwing Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: given name COMPACT_CTOR_DEF

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, gradle-plugin

I've recently added the checkstyle plugin to the project for static code analysis. But after updating the `google-style.xml` from the latest master, I've started receiving the below exception :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: given name COMPACT_CTOR_DEF
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:80)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:162)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.AntBuilderDelegate.nodeCompleted(AntBuilderDelegate.java:124)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleInvoker$_invoke_closure1.doCall(CheckstyleInvoker.groovy:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder$2.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.java:154)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder$2.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.ClassPathToClassLoaderCache.withCachedClassLoader(ClassPathToClassLoaderCache.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.java:130)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.IsolatedAntBuilder$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleInvoker.invoke(CheckstyleInvoker.groovy:51)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.run(Checkstyle.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:717)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:684)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: given name COMPACT_CTOR_DEF
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.utils.TokenUtil.getTokenId(TokenUtil.java:174)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.registerCheck(TreeWalker.java:212)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:130)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:201)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:477)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:201)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.createRootModule(CheckstyleAntTask.java:421)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.realExecute(CheckstyleAntTask.java:320)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.execute(CheckstyleAntTask.java:302)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        ... 111 more
```

The xml file that is being used : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

The configuration for my checkstyle plugin is as below :

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '8.35'
    configFile = file("$projectDir/google_checks.xml")
    showViolations = true
    ignoreFailures = false
}
```

The gradle version I'm using :

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-09-05 16:13:54 UTC
Revision:     55a5e53d855db8fc7b0e494412fc624051a8e781

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          11.0.4 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.4+10-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

Any help or pointers to as what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using google_checks file from master branch, which means the latest version, and it may have things which will be supported only in next release.
It is mentioned in [docs](https://checkstyle.org/google_style.html#Google_Coverage_table)

> ATTENTION: Links to config and test in following table reference to latest (not released yet) config. Config might be slightly different from what we have in latest release. Please always use config that is embedded to jar or use a custom version copied from one that matches your checkstyle version.

This is exactly your case, since token COMPACT_CTOR_DEF was added after 8.35 release.

Best practice here is to use embedded google style, which is tested and working fine.

Update (from my comment to this answer):

To find google_checks.xml for some checkstyle version without searching in jar file do following (will not work for very old checkstyle versions)

1. Open releases [page](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases)
2. Scroll to release you are interested in and click on "checkstyle-<your_version>" link above commit hash. It will open code at this commit.
3. Navigate to `src/main/resources/` there you can see google_checks.xml file.

Comment: Where can we find `google_checks.xml` in the jar file? I unpacked the entire jar, but can't find it. I'm using Checkstyle v3.1.1.

Comment: I found it in `com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle`. I must say, this tool is not very user-friendly.

Comment: There is a different way (will not work for very old checkstyle versions)
--> Open releases page https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases
--> Scroll to release you are interested in and click on commit hash. It will open you code at this commit
--> Navigate to `src/main/resources/` there you can see google_checks.xml file.

Comment: >To find google_checks.xml for some checkstyle version without searching in jar file

Answer (score 4):

> To find google_checks.xml for some checkstyle version without searching in jar file

Find your release https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases

Click on tag name for this release, for example https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/tree/checkstyle-8.40

Click in "Go to file" button and search for google_checks.xml.
Use raw format of file.

Comment: I followed that approach and I still get the same error